# How to get this type of fonts in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: vs]
I have seen many people using this type of fonts..
I always wanted to use this fonts in my vs code..

Comment: This is just the italic version of a font (operator mono iirc). So you just have to install the font

Comment: and choose a theme that has comments italic or customize a theme to have italic fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this type of font. You can choose two style which are (**Operator mono iirc** or **Fira Code**).

I will just show you how to download and setup **Fira Code** which will give you experience like the image that mentioned in your question.

1. Go to [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Fira+Code?query=Fira%20Code&preview.text=Isn%27t&preview.text_type=custom) then download **Family** and a zip file should be
   downloaded on your Machine.
2. Unzip the downloaded font zip file. Then Click on
   install to install into your Machine.
3. In your Visual Studio Code
   Go to `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings` and search for downloaded font which is **Fira
   Code.**

**Notice** : If you did not see effect of the new font. You might need to restart your Machine to see effect.

**Tip** : You might want to enable font ligatures. it also makes font looks better.

A big Thanks for @solexy79 in (https://dev.to/solexy79/installing-a-new-font-for-vs-code-in-three-3-simple-steps-13a5).

A Big Thanks for @somerandomdev49 in comments.